# Does Firebase support email addresses with Unicode character like smart apostrophes (’)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a user using the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and the email id which i used to register have smart apostrophes which unicode is U+2019. for example `trap’py@gmail.com`.  User created successful but while sending the email verification link to the user using the `firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification` function i get an error that
`

```
{"code":"auth/invalid-recipient-email","message":"Missing recipients"}
```

NOTE: This work fine if i use only ASCII character in my email instead of NO-ASCII character.

I try with other non-ASCII character and get the same result. In the documentation, did not find any information regarding the international email address. [Send a user a verification email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)